# Zeroes appearing when reading file (where aren't any)

Tags: python, csv, file-io, encoding

When reading a file (UTF-8 Unicode text, csv) with Python on Linux, either with:

- csv.reader()
- file()

values of some columns get a zero as their first characeter (there are no zeroues in input), other get a few zeroes, which are not seen when viewing file with Geany or any other editor. For example:

Input

```
10016;9167DE1;Tom;Sawyer ;Street 22;2610;Wil;;378983561;tom@hotmail.com;1979-08-10 00:00:00.000;0;1;Wil;081208608;NULL;2;IZMH726;2010-08-30 15:02:55.777;2013-06-24 08:17:22.763;0;1;1;1;NULL
```

Output

```
10016;9167DE1;Tom;Sawyer ;Street 22;2610;Wil;;0378983561;tom@hotmail.com;1979-08-10 00:00:00.000;0;1;Wil;081208608;NULL;2;IZMH726;2010-08-30 15:02:55.777;2013-06-24 08:17:22.763;0;1;1;1;NULL
```

See 378983561 > 0378983561
Reading with:

```
f = file('/home/foo/data.csv', 'r')
data = f.read()
split_data = data.splitlines()
lines = list(line.split(';') for line in split_data)
print data[51220][8]
>>> '0378983561' #should have been '478983561' (reads like this in Geany etc.)
```

Same result with csv.reader().

Help me solve the mystery, what could be the cause of this? Could it be related to encoding/decoding?

Comment: Please provide the input file contents, output contents, expected output and the code you are using to read it.

Comment: I have updated my question. I cannot publish exact input unfortunately.

Comment: Does the input data include leading zeroes?

Comment: No, no leading zeroes in input. No leading zeroes visible when viewing file in text editor like Geany.

Comment: Please make some anonymised sample data. It doesn't have to be the exact data, just make sure that your program behaves the same way. It's very difficult to help otherwise.

Comment: I think your claim that there are no leading zeros is mistaken, at least according to the csv.reader rules otherwise you wouldn't get `'047…'`.

Comment: Yes, it might be my claim is wrong, but why no zeroes visible in input?

Comment: @atman - we cannot tell you unless you tell us what the input is.

Comment: I have updated my question with two lines, an input line from file, and an output for the same line. Thank you.

Comment: Great, thanks. Your program doesn't produce that output though. Please post your whole program, or at least the bit that produces that output. I think the problem is in a bit of the program we can't see.

Comment: For example, if I run your program on the input data, I get `lines[0][8] = '378983561'`.

Answer (score 0):

The data you're getting is a string.

```
print data[51220][8]
>>> '0478983561'
```

If you want to use this as an integer, you should parse it.

```
print int(data[51220][8])
>>> 478983561
```

If you want this as a string, you should convert it back to a string.

```
print repr(int(data[51220][8]))
>>> '478983561'
```

Comment: Okay, but where does zero come from (or why), when there is no zero in input text?

Comment: You tell me. I can't see what's on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

csv.reader treats all columns as strings. Conversion to the appropriate type is up to you as in:

```
print int(data[51220][8])
```